How to pass video frames to Conv3D in Tensorflow 2.x and Keras to do grouped convolution?
I am trying to build a module described in the article:
take a look at the article, please. Thus, I am trying to use Conv3D in TensorFlow to implement GConv and Multi-group Block as described in the article. The problem is that I am new to this field and don't know how to pass video frames to Conv3D for a group convolution.
Can someone show me step-by-step code of how to do it?
